# How do you decide on denoting a member function in C++ and/or python as static?

Tags: python, c++

How do you decide on denoting a member function in C++ and/or python
as static?

Comment: It depends if you need it by instance of the class, or just for the whole class (like a instance counter, or a fixed value)

Answer (score 0):

When your member function doesn't use any of the member variables, and doesn't call any other nonstatic member functions (of the same class), it can be static itself.